# Trying to get new value from a component on custom table cell class

Tags: ios, swift, tablecell

I have an app which have a table view

and iam using custom cell class in my table

and this is my custom table cell class :

```
class addCommentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        postText.layer.borderWidth = 1
        postText.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor

        postText.layer.cornerRadius = 3


    }

    @IBOutlet weak var postText: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var postCommentButton: UIButton!
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

i need to click the button in the cell class and get the value from the textView

so i added this code to make that :

```
   class singleNewViewController: UIViewController  , UITableViewDataSource  , UITableViewDelegate{

         override func viewDidLoad() {

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)

            let secondCellPostComment = mainTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addCommentCell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! addCommentTableViewCell


            let postButton =    secondCellPostComment.postCommentButton

             postButton!.addTarget(self, action: "postUserComment", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)



          }

    func postUserComment()
        {


            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
            let secondCellPostComment = mainTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addCommentCell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! addCommentTableViewCell

        var textFieldComment = secondCellPostComment.postText
            let textF =    textFieldComment.text!



           let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:  "http://mydomain/comment")!)


             request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "user_id=\(addResourcesViewController.userLoggedID)&news_id=\(singleNewViewController.newID)&comment=\(textF.text!)"
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data , response , error in

                guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }


                if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response)")
                }


                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.mainTable.reloadData()

                })

            }
            task.resume()     
        }





func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if (indexPath.row == 0 )
        {
        let cell = mainTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("singleTableDetails", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! singleNewTableViewCell










        let readmorebutton = cell.readmore
        let focusComment = cell.addcomments



            readmorebutton.addTarget(self, action: "loadURLinBrowser", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


            focusComment.addTarget(self, action: "focusToView", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


            let remoteImageUrlString = "http://mydomian/"+singleNewViewController.image
            let imageURL = NSURL(string: remoteImageUrlString)

            let myBlock: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = { (image:UIImage! , error : NSError! , cacheType: SDImageCacheType! , imageURL: NSURL! ) -> Void in
                print("Image with urk  \(imageURL.absoluteString) is loaded" )

            }


            cell.cellImage.sd_setImageWithURL(imageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"welcome_bg") , options: SDWebImageOptions.ProgressiveDownload, completed: myBlock)



       return cell

        }else if (indexPath.row == 1 )
        {
            let cell = mainTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addCommentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! addCommentTableViewCell





           return cell
        }


        else
        {
            let cell = mainTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("allCommentsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! commentsTableViewCell
            cell.commentUser.text = self.commentsUser[(indexPath.row - 2)]
            cell.comment.text = self.comments[(indexPath.row - 2)]

                return cell
        }


    }
}
```

the code is working but i don't get the value of the **UITextView**

and i tried to add a default value to the UITextView from the storyboard  it's working but when i run in simulator  and  replace it with any string it's send the default value to the url any suggestion why it's not read any new values  ?

Comment: what you written in celllForRowAtIndexPath function

Comment: where you assign postText.text = response data?

Comment: var textFieldComment = secondCellPostComment.postText
            let textF =    textFieldComment.text!



           let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:  "http://mydomain/comment")!)
  request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
 let postString = "user_id=\(addResourcesViewController.userLoggedID)&news_id=\(singleNewViewController.newID)&comment=\(textF.text!)"